# TypeError: Return value of class::functionName() must be an instance of /Interface, null returned

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, prophecy

How to specify a return type of function (an instance of Interface) using php prophecy.

method is like:-

```
class classname()
{
  public $var;

public functionName : Interface
{

   return $this->var;

}

}
```

IS it possible to do something like this? $this->method->willreturn(string)->ofTypeInterface

Comment: If that is your actual function, there is no value returned, so it can't be of type `Interface`.

Comment: No am returning a property of class inside that function!

Comment: The problem is that your showing incomplete code which is impossible to guess what your doing.  How is `$var` being set?

Comment: Oh ok..can you please tell me how to write testcase for  a return type of a method as interface type..as i mentioned in code!

Answer (score 6):

Php return types do not allow a null value by default, so if you specify that the function should return an `Interface` it can **only** return an interface object.

So you should either return an Interface object or if you also want to allow null values you should to the following:

```
public functionName : ?Interface
{

}
```

This will accept either an `Interface` object or null to be returned